# Data annotation Required in Entity Framework Core with MySQL seems to work incorrectly

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, data-annotations, nullable, non-nullable

In my project, I have a table:

```
[Table("users")]
public class User
{
    [Column("id"), Key, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name"), MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The property `Name` is not flagged with `Required` data annotation. However, in the generated migration, I see this code:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "users",
    columns: table => new
    {
        id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        .Annotation("MySQL:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySQLValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(64)", maxLength: 64, nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_users", x => x.id);
    })
    .Annotation("MySQL:Charset", "utf8mb4");
```

The nullable property of the `Name` column should be true as long as I am not marking it as `Required`, shouldn't it?

I am using EF Core 7.0.7 with the `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` 7.0.2 (newest) package.

How to fix this?

Of course I can manually replace the nullable property by hand in the migration file, but that's a lot of work and offers potential for mistakes...

I also know the FluentAPI declarations, but I prefer using data annotations.

With FluentAPI the nullable property in the migration file is set correctly.

Comment: Add reference type nullability `public string? Name { get; set; }`